# How to remove podspecs completely from Xcode and repo?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I've a project with huge codebase and it has 4 different target Apps.

Now there are many of views, models and controllers are common for all 4 target apps. So those common files, classes and image assets are placed in `central` folder and that folder is act as pod library. I've to run `pod install` to fetch all `central` code dependencies.

Here is how my `Podfile` file looks like.

```
#Pod sources
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://bitbucket.org/ttttt/xxxxxxxx.git'
source 'https://xx-xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxxx.git'

# Use the same pod library for all these targets
def myPods
    pod 'ABC', :path => '.' #'ABC' is name of pods in .podspecs file, which I want to remove
end

target 'target1' do
    myPods
end

target 'target2' do
    myPods
end

target 'target3' do
    myPods
end

target 'target4' do
    myPods
end
```

Here, ABC is project name. and it imports `ABC.podspecs` at local path.

Now, I want to remove `ABC.podspecs` files and make all code locally (not as pod library).

Can anybody please suggest me how to do that?
If I remove it directly and run `pod install`, it gives lots of errors and architecture issues.

Comment: pod deintegrate https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_deintegrate

Comment: it helped me to remove my pod project, but it also removes all other useful pods too. I just want to remove my project files, assets (`central` folder) from pods and want to add it in bundle to use as bundle, not as pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!

What I did is, moved all dependency targets into PodFile. and then removed `ProjectName.podspecs` file from the project. Then deleted Pods, pod lock file and workspace, and run `pod install` again.
This process removed all development pods and dependencies from the pods project.

After that, for all `central` files, classes, assets, I've set all 4 target as `target membership` from right inspector in Xcode. and it worked well.